# Calling finish() on Activty Guarantees onCreate in launch?

Tags: android

I want to know if I call finish() on an activity, is guaranteed that onDestroy() will be called on it and then later when activity is started it will not be resume but rather onCreate() will be called ?

This I want to know because I am facing a weird bug and getting into its details is irrelevant here, so I would appreciate if someone can confirm that above assumption is true or not

Comment: There is so many questions about android life cycle here on SO! However about your bug experience, "it will not be resume but rather". You might misunderstand the intentional behavior of onResume? onResume is always called, even after onCreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Android documentation for [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class defines, `finish()` will indeed cause your `Activity` to be destroyed, thus `onDestroy()` **will** be called:

> **onDestroy()**
>   The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Now if you look at the `Activity` lifecycle diagram:

[image: Activity lifecycle diagram]

you'll see that once the `Activity` is shut down, it will be recreated from scratch, meaning that `onCreate()` **will** be called.